# CudaMalloc fails while allocating memory

Tags: c++, cuda

I am trying to allocate a large amount of memory on GPU using cudaMalloc:   `cudaMalloc((void**)&count_d, N*sizeof(long));`
with

```
unsigned long N = 999999999L;
```

I got an error message an that place so the question is if I am allocating too much memory or am doing something else wrong.

The error message what I get :

```
CUDA error : an illegal memory access was encountered (77)
```

Comment: Depends, do you have 4 GB of space on your GPU?

Comment: Probably worth a read: [What is the canonical way to check for errors using the CUDA runtime API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api)

Comment: @alter igel. Indeed, thre is 4GB space on GPU.  I have used an illegal memory access was encountered (77). I have used the API function to check it: cudaSuccess != cudaMalloc( &count_d, N*sizeof(long), but the error was: an illegal memory access was encountered (77).  Do you know how I can check how much memory I'm allocating in bytes?

Comment: More useful to post the exact error message than only describe it.

Comment: @chux Just added

Comment: Please take the time to read some documentation https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g37d37965bfb4803b6d4e59ff26856356 . That error doesn't come from cudaMalloc, it comes from something earlier in your code, probably a kernel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @talonmies said, and as the [`cudaMalloc()` documentation tells you](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g37d37965bfb4803b6d4e59ff26856356), calling `cudaMalloc()` cannot trigger an "illegal memory access" error - that's about an illegal access by *device* code. (Host-side code making illegal memory accesses results in a SIGSEGV signal on Unix or a Protection Fault on Windows).

So how is it possible you're seeing this error after your `cudaMalloc()`? Simple: It happened earlier, and you simply weren't checking for errors before; or you weren't synchronizing your streams to have pending kernels executed.

Finally, consider following the link @alterIgel posted as a comment, to read about proper error checking of CUDA API calls.